# Hard to find bug that involves strange physics behaviour in pygame code

Tags: python, pygame

First I'll say I'm pretty tired I've been up about 22 hours straight. Anyway I have this funky physics problem in a PONG game. You know the old classic. I have been looking at the code for a LONG time trying different variation, commenting out certain parts etc. and I can't find the damn bug!

Can someone give me a hand, please?

It's the physics for the ball that's a problem. It bounces off the top and bottom the screen fine when going left just fine.

But I can't send it going back to the right after it collides with paddle coming to from the left. It just forces bounces off a bit and forces it's way back and over the paddle?!

However I can send the ball right when I program it to bounce right after hitting one of the top or bottom sides, so I don't think there is anything wrong with the actual code that moves the ball to the right.

But that movement to right is the opposite of the desired physics for the game, so it's useless because it's supposed to bounce off and go right when it hits the paddle on the left, it's not supposed to "force" it self over the paddle and go left.

It's actually kind of funny if you could see it:)

Can anybody make sense of this and give me an explanation for this?

[code]

```
    # move the ball around

    # if the ball disappears off the either side of the screen, send it back heading  left
    if ballRect.left > WINDOWWIDTH or ballRect.right < 0:
        direction = getRandomDirection()
        ballRect.center = (WINDOWWIDTH - ballRect.width, random.randint(100, 200))

    if direction == 'downleft':
        ballRect.left -= BALLSPEEDX
        ballRect.top += BALLSPEEDY
    if direction == 'upleft':
        ballRect.left -= BALLSPEEDX
        ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY
    if direction == 'downright':
        ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX
        ballRect.top += BALLSPEEDY
    if direction == 'upright':
        ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX
        ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY

    if ballRect.top < 0:
        if direction == 'upleft':
            direction = 'downleft'
        if direction == 'upright':
            direction = 'downright'
    if ballRect.bottom > WINDOWHEIGHT:
        if direction == 'downleft':
            direction = 'upleft'
        if direction == 'downright':
            direction = 'upright'

    if paddleRect.colliderect(ballRect):
        if direction == 'upleft':
            direction = 'upright'
            ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX
            ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY
        if direction == 'upright':
            direction = 'upleft'
            ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX
            ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY
        if direction == 'downleft':
            direction = 'upleft'
            ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX
            ballRect.top += BALLSPEEDY
        if direction == 'downright':
            direction = 'upright'
            ballRect.left -= BALLSPEEDX
            ballRect.top += BALLSPEEDY
```

[/code]

Comment: You'd do well to add some more comments in your text and check the one you have already... Seems to me that if the ball just gets out of the screen, it reappears in the centre, but not going "left", but going in a random direction. And it is impossible for me to interpret your code without comments explaining, remember we can not play with it and change things!

Comment: wouldn't some `elif`s make more sense??

Comment: @Jblaco I was aware that there are too few comments. I will add the comments, but first I have to go dentist. :-) And then I have to go to work so I'll try to add them while I'm in transit.

Comment: @gnibbler maybe. I will think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `directions == 'upleft'`, both these blocks will execute

```
if paddleRect.colliderect(ballRect):
    if direction == 'upleft':
        direction = 'upright'
        ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX * 4
        ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY * 4
    if direction == 'upright':
        direction = 'upleft'
        ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX * 4
        ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY * 4
```

Probably should be more like this

```
if paddleRect.colliderect(ballRect):
    if direction == 'upleft':
        direction = 'upright'
        ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX * 4
        ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY * 4
    elif direction == 'upright':
        direction = 'upleft'
        ballRect.left += BALLSPEEDX * 4
        ballRect.top -= BALLSPEEDY * 4
    elif ...
```

Comment: Yes, of course... that would be avoided with "elif". Well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `direction`, you can bounce like this:

```
if collide with left/right wall:
    xvel *= -1
if collide with top/bot wall:
    yvel *= -1

# then always
ball.rect.left += xvel
ball.rect.top += yvel
```